# How to get properties of SpecResult in the Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, selenium, jasmine

How to get access to the status property of SpecResult type of Global in the afterEach block in the Jasmine ver. 4.5?

I'm using bare Jasmine (with no Protracktor or WebDriverIO) and Selenium. I'd like to take screenshots only for tests that failed.

How can I get access to the current test status in the afterEach block?

I've tried this:

```
let status = jasmine.getEnv.SpecResult.status
let status = jasmine.getEnv().SpecResult.status
let status = jasmine.SpecResult.status
let status = this.SpecResult.status
```

But all of these got or 'undefined' or 'cannot read property of ...'